# how to get variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have script in `aspx` page so I want that variable value in another JavaScript file.

```
function ValidateStartDate() 
{
   var txtDate = document.getElementById('<%=txtDateFilterActv.ClientID  %>');
   var lastdate = txtDate.value;
}
```

After click on save button I want '`lastdate`' variable value in another JavaScript file. How can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

txtDate.value is correct? you can easy test it with "alert(txtDate.value);"
if it is correct you declare var lastdate outside the function (global) and then you can read in other javascript function.
bye.
example:

```
var lastdate;
function ValidateStartDate() 
{
   var txtDate = document.getElementById('<%=txtDateFilterActv.ClientID  %>');
   lastdate = txtDate.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two files:

```
<script src="/test1.js"></script>

<script src="/test2.js"></script>
```

You could then change **test1.js** to:

```
var global = {};
global.settings = {
    valid_start_date: ValidateStartDate
  };
```

And then from **test2.js** you could use *global* like a scoped variable:

```
console.log(global.settings.valid_start_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var lastdate;
var ValidateStartDate = function(){
   var txtDate = document.getElementById('<%=txtDateFilterActv.ClientID  %>');
   var lastdate = txtDate.value;
   return lastdate;
}
lastdate = ValidateStartDate();
alert(lastdate);
```